# Is the word "stage" used correctly in this meaning?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> They are at the **stage** in which they are.

I mean they are where they are, with things which they got. For example they don’t have a big house, they have average house and this is okay to have this average house. They have 30 millions dollars, they want 40 millions, but this doesn’t change the fact that they have 30 millions now. They are where they are.

My dictionary doesn't explain it.

Comment: Your sentence seems meaningless, and your two examples mean different things. The house owners are content with their present circumstances. The millionaires seem to aspire to be richer.

Comment: ***We are where we are*** is idiomatically well established (as is ***The situation is what it is***, to a lesser extent). But ***They are at the stage in which they are*** has no currency, AND it's inherently "clumsy" because it pointlessly switches the preposition from ***at*** to ***in*** (destroying the symmetry that's effectively the ***only*** reason we tolerate the two alternatives I've just given).

Answer (score 2):

I would say:

> They want 40 millions, but *that's **(the stage) where** they are now.*

Yes, you can use the noun ***stage*** with this meaning:

> A point or step in a process or development ([WordHippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/stage.html))

However, the expression ***they are where they are*** is the most common, not the expression with ***stage*** as you can see from [Gngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=they%20are%20where%20they%20are%2Cthat%20is%20where%20they%20are%2C%20the%20stage%20where%20they%20are&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthey%20are%20where%20they%20are%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthat%20is%20where%20they%20are%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20stage%20where%20they%20are%3B%2Cc0).